# Fix segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a postfix to infix program using two stacks. The basic idea is this -

ptr1  -->  ptr2 --> ptr3 --> ptr4 --> NULL

|    --------- | --------   |  ---------   |

(4*5) ----5  --------  6  --------   10

Each operand is a separate stack and the ptr stack is for the memory address of first element of each operand. But I am getting a segmentation error. I think it is due to the
(*ptr) = (*ptr)->next1;   statement in the pop function. Can someone explain/fix this to make a pop function that  returns the address of the operand stack at the top and pops the ptr stack  at the same time?  Complete code -

```
struct bracket {
  char c;
  struct bracket* next;
};

struct outer {
    struct bracket *down;
    struct outer *next1;
};
struct outer* push_ptr (struct bracket *ptr,struct outer * out){
    struct outer *temp = NULL;
    temp = (struct outer*)malloc(sizeof(struct outer));
    temp->down = ptr;
    temp->next1 = out;
    return temp;
}

struct bracket* push_ch(char ch,struct bracket *head){

  struct bracket *temp = NULL;
  temp = (struct bracket*)malloc(sizeof(struct bracket));
  temp->c = ch;
  temp->next = head;
  return temp;
}

struct bracket* pop(struct outer **ptr){
  struct bracket *top = (struct bracket*)malloc(sizeof(struct bracket));
  top = (*ptr)->down;
  (*ptr) = (*ptr)->next1;
  return top;
}

int main(){

    char c[] = "25,9,6,/,-,3,/";
    struct outer * address = NULL;
    struct bracket * num;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(c);i=i+1){
        
        if(c[i]==',') continue;
        
        else if (c[i]=='*' || c[i]=='-' || c[i]=='+' || c[i]=='/'){
            struct bracket *top1 = pop(&address);
            struct bracket *top2 = pop(&address);
            
        } 
        
        else {
               num = NULL;
               while(c[i]!=','){
                   num = push_ch(c[i],num);
                   i = i+1;
               }               
               address = push_ptr(num,address);
               
        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "I think it is due to the (*ptr) = (*ptr)->next1; statement in the pop function." If you step through the program with a debugger, you'll know for sure.

Comment: Probably not directly contributing to the problem you are asking but `num = push_ch(c[i],num);` seems problematic for the more general task. That pushes one character and doesn't seem like it will handle numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger but when I removed that statement, there was no segmentation fault. @Passerby

Comment: I could think of no other way. But that's why I used a while loop so that I could have multi digits numbers stored as a single linked list (num). @kaylum

Comment: Learning to use a debugger will save you countless hours, especially on problems like this. It's essential. Strongly recommend that you make it your first priority!

Comment: You can use a function like `atoi` or `strtol` to convert a string to a number and then push the value as an integer instead of a character.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on it  {kaylum, Passerby}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is definitely in the function pop()...

```
struct bracket* pop(struct outer **ptr){
  struct bracket *top = (struct bracket*)malloc(sizeof(struct bracket));
  top = (*ptr)->down;
  (*ptr) = (*ptr)->next1;
  return top;
}
```

You are poping from the outer ptr every time and eventually, at some point, it will remain empty. Let us understand what will happen when it is empty. So you pass a reference struct outer **ptr which points to NULL. Hence it will not be able to retrieve (*ptr)->down on this line ...

```
top = (*ptr)->down;
```

And You will have a segmentation fault.
You should treat the NULL case in your pop function (in general it is good to NULL protect every function). An alternate implementation of the pop function could be this...

```
struct bracket* pop(struct outer **ptr){
  struct bracket *top = (struct bracket*)malloc(sizeof(struct bracket));
  if (*ptr)
  {
      top = (*ptr)->down;
      (*ptr) = (*ptr)->next1;
  }
  else
      top = NULL;
  return top;
}
```

This will fix the segmentation fault. It will return NULL if the outer struct contains no elements.

Comment: Thank you @Sargis Hovsepyan. This was indeed the case and it is working now.

Comment: @Nimish You are welcome! Also, I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!